# ¿Cómo instalo wordpress en heroku? con postgres

Tags: wordpress, heroku

Esta es mi página la cual me pide una base de datos http://tenlo.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php esto es producto de lo que he subido con gitbash, también he  instalado sobre mi aplicacion de heroku postgres con esta página https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] ¿que debo de escribir donde dice base de datos usuario y contraseña? he intentando escribir esto pero no funciona [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]